# Some keyboard keys not working in Ubuntu 16.04LTS and none working on Windows. But working fine in BIOS

Tags: 16.04, kernel, keyboard, asus

I have an Asus A540L laptop running dual boot on Ubuntu 16.04LTS and Windows 10 since last 1 year. Recently since 5-6 days, i've been experiencing keyboard and mouse issues. First, the left arrow button on my laptop keyboard seemed to get stuck. Then I switched to Windows and shockingly, none of the keys on my keyboard works at all(despite the keyboard works in Ubuntu). Then i went to BIOS during startup to check if it wasn't a hardware fault, and all the keys worked fine there. I even reinstalled `xserver-xorg` and `libinput` as well. Today, some of the keys(like, 'u',left arrow key,backspace key etc.) stopped working on ubuntu as well. But everything works fine in BIOS. So, i hope this may not be the Hardware, but kernel issue. Can some please help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your keyboard by booting into the BIOS.
If it works there, then your hardware is OK.

Then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

in the terminal and choose the appropriate keybord. Asus should be in the list.

Comment: how do you check the keyboard in bios?