# Keyboard periodically stops working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, io

As the title says, I am having issues with my keyboard, where it will stop working after a period of roughly 20-30 minutes (it is difficult to get an exact time). While it is working, it works perfectly well, but after the time is up it just stops working, even when I am mid typing. I don't think it is a usb power issue, as the back-light stays on. Here is some more information on my setup, what I do now, and what I've tried.

**Setup**

- My computer is a desktop pc which I built.
- As stated, I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I want to add that I am running a dual-boot with Windows on the other partition. The keyboard works perfectly on Windows.
- My keyboard is an obinslab Anne Pro 2, and as far as I can tell, it is running the newest drivers.
- This keyboard is capable of Bluetooth, but as I am fine with wires I am running it through USB.
- I am also using a mouse, which is not experiencing any issues

**Current fix**

- Right now, all I have to do is unplug the keyboard and re-plug it in to get it working again. After the ~20 minutes, I have to repeat this step.
- I wanted to add that when first booting (ie going through BIOS and choosing OS to run), the keyboard works fine. Once it starts-up Ubuntu though the keyboard becomes disconnected.

**What I've tried**

- I have tried both solutions provided by the top answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus), but they don't seem to work for me. They both work around the autosuspend, which doesn't seem to be the issue for me.
- Similarly I have tried [this](https://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/index.html), but it is also not working. As far as I can tell, this also works around the auto suspend
- The solution provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952934/some-keyboard-keys-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04lts-and-none-working-on-windows-b) seems plausible, but my keyboard is not provided in the list. So I am not too sure that would work.I an afraid to try this one though as I do not know what kind of changes it would incur. (This link has you run a command which then allows you to select your keyboard from a list. But that list only has commonly available keyboards)

I will include below the output from running `sudo dmesg`:

> [14589.078032] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
>
> [14589.249729] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=a292, bcdDevice= 1.00
>
> [14589.249733] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>
> [14589.249735] usb 3-4: Product: OBINS AnnePro2
>
> [14589.249737] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: OBINS
>
> [14589.249739] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: SN0000000001
>
> [14589.310209] input: OBINS OBINS AnnePro2 as/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb3/3-4/34:1.0/0003:04D9:A292.0033/input/input68
>
> [14589.369897] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A292.0033: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [OBINS OBINS AnnePro2] on usb-0000:0b:00.3-4/input0
>
> [14589.376039] input: OBINS OBINS AnnePro2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.1/0003:04D9:A292.0034/input/input69
>
> [14589.376183] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A292.0034: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [OBINS OBINS AnnePro2] on usb-0000:0b:00.3-4/input1
>
> [14589.383073] input: OBINS OBINS AnnePro2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.2/0003:04D9:A292.0035/input/input70
>
> [14589.441899] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A292.0035: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [OBINS OBINS AnnePro2] on usb-0000:0b:00.3-4/input2
>
> [14589.448116] input: OBINS OBINS AnnePro2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.3/0003:04D9:A292.0036/input/input71
>
> [14589.448303] hid-generic 0003:04D9:A292.0036: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Gamepad [OBINS OBINS AnnePro2] on usb-0000:0b:00.3-4/input3
>
> [15139.992974] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 6 [16467.236105] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 18

Let me know what kind of solutions I can use for this, I've been trying to come up with something, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: It would be helpful for users trying to provide a solution if you could edit your question and include a brief indication of the second and third possible solutions, i.e. "this" and "here", that you have tried.  You do this for the first "here" which is an autosuspend fix.  Similar descriptions may avoid users having to go to the links to check the issues and possibly provide you with a solution a little faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I edited the links missing descriptions. Let me know if there are any other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it seems that the problem is not with Ubuntu, but actually with the keyboard firmware. This is my fault as I did not think to check if the AnnePro2 has a subreddit, which it apparently does. The solution can be found [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/AnnePro/comments/glrg3c/ap2_stop_on_arch_linux/).