# Machine locks up, cannot type or click

Tags: 20.04

For some reason my Ubuntu machine will suddenly stop accepting input from my keyboard or mouse, I can't click or type anything. How can I diagnose the problem and find the cause? I played with the mouse settings a month ago to try to disable the scrollbar click (middle click on my mouse).

It happens unpredictably as far as I can tell - if that's any clue, usually 5-30 minutes after I reboot my machine.

Comment: Add your computer make and model and any specs you know.  List all changes you have done plus version of Ubuntu.  Did computer work well before and this new?  Have you cleaned computer of dust or know what temperature it is running at?  Do you know if just keyboard/mouse stop working or Ubuntu freezing?  Do you need restart for them to work again?

Comment: re-installed ubuntu 4 months ago, has been working fine until a week ago, normal conditions, perhaps Ubuntu freezes, it's hard to tell

Comment: it's a dell XPS 15" with ubuntu 20.04 installed on it

Comment: Any chance you have an extra keyboard/mouse handy?  Should tell if laptop keyboard/mouse problem or Ubuntu freezing.

Comment: yeah I do have extra mouse, how do go about that?

Comment: Just plug it in, if it works/moves Ubuntu not frozen.  Can see this link for ideas.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261721/keyboard-periodically-stops-working-in-ubuntu-20-04?rq=1